# Compare to columns, identify duplicates in a 3rd column

Tags: excel

Excel 2003 / Windows XP

I have two columns of email addresses, A with 13,000 entries and B with 6000 entries. I need to compare B with A and identify emails in B that are not found in A. So that I end up with a list of all those emails from B somehow.

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/81498/excel-find-items-in-one-column-that-are-not-in-another-column

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one off?

If so, a manual process is

1. Add a formula to `C2` of `=MATCH(B2,A:A,0)` (Lets assume you have a header row)
2. Apply AutoFilter to the whole range `A:C`
3. Filter column `C` for `#N/A`, so only `#N/A` values show in column `C`
4. Select the values in column `B`, and copy / paster to another range

These copied values are your list of missing addresses

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes this is a once or twice type thing. When I got to step three, I ended up with this result. (using numbers instead)

1 3 3
2 6 6
3 43 #N/A
4 4 4
5 2 2
6  #N/A
7  #N/A

In step 2 & 3 do you mean to AutoFilter #N/A for just C? If so, I'm not understanding step 4.